# Noob Question About Python Web Automation

Tags: python, web, browser, automation, scripting

I've been learning HTML and CSS for about a year, I’m a massive noob at Python and I would like someone to clear some things up for me if possible.

I'm wanting to use a browser extension to automate some work tasks, there's a few good ones that work with JS but I'd like to focus on Python.

I understand that python would require a interpreter to work, I've ran some basic scripts on my PC but I don't understand how you'd execute scrips externally on the web.

Do web browsers have a built in interpreter?

Are there such extensions that exist?

And if so do they have interpreters built in?

Python is a brand new concept to me and I apologise if this is a stupid question. I aim to get the basics down first and then pick up a Raspberry Pi for some project work.

Comment: Depending on the kind of automation tasks you want to do, you may want to look into Selenium, which is a third-party python module that automates tasks in browsers.

Comment: Form filling, navigating links and scraping data. I will look into selenium then. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

> Do web browsers have a built in interpreter?

They have a JavaScript console in dev tools instead of python